# How do I add a WebSVN RSS to feed to Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, rss

I am unable to connect to an RSS feed in Outlook due to the following error:

```
Outlook cannot process the RSS content from https://localhost/websvn/rss.php?repname=demo_engine&path=%2F&isdir=1&. The link may not point to a valid RSS source.
```

Is there a setting anywhere in WebSVN or Outlook that I can tweak to get this? I can confirm that entering this URL in my web browser does display XML.

Comment: Does it do that on another machine? Sometimes "localhost" can cause problems with dynamic content and resolution etc. (like xmlhttp objects)
Is there any "Authentication" settings or is it open to anonymous viewers?

Comment: Yes, it does do that on other machines. I have a self-signed certificate, but there is no authentication set up.